# Linear Algebra Done Wrong -- Appropriate for first course?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

The book 'Linear Algebra Done Wrong' has been highly recommended in many threads and comments here. However, I couldn't find much consensus or discussion on whether this book is both **appropriate for self-study** and **appropriate for a first course in Linear Algebra**.

As an undergraduate with no background in linear algebra other than basic matrix computations, is this resource appropriate as an introductory book for a self-learner?

Comment: Don't worry, it is a good book for any case. After this, you can also start reading Linear Algebra by Hoffman &  Kunze.

Comment: If you're talking about https://www.math.brown.edu/~treil/papers/LADW/LADW.html : This is a book that assumes no prior familiarity with matrices, but it assumes some familiarity with mathematical proofs. If you are starting out without the latter, you should first go through one of the many "introduction to proofs" / "transition to advanced maths" resources.